# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in Laravel while API writing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am developing APIs using Laravel and I am new to it. I am using following method as route for my api but facing error.

Route in api.php:

```
Route::post('user/register','UserController@Register')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

Is there any setting or something else which I have missed.

Comment: and how are you accessing the route?

Comment: Aren't  you requesting a `get` request ?

Comment: I am using http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/register to access it using postman and selected post method.

Comment: Try it to access like: 127.0.0.1:8000/user with `POST` method!

Comment: I see the following error then...Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: Are you trying to create a user using this api?

Comment: yes I am trying to create user

Comment: Are you added any prefix with this route? Make sure there is no any prefix added. If you added it, please use it when you call the route! If possible, post your whole `route.php/web.php/api.php` file here.

Comment: First of all you should dump your routes in the console with php artisan route:list and see how it looks.

Comment: I ran the command php artisan route:list and showed route like api/user/register. I tried to call method by the given url and its now showing InvalidArgumentException
Route [login] not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `/api` in your url when you trying to access api routes, so it should look like this `127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/register`

Comment: I am facing the same issue still

Comment: show how you trying to access the route, and also do you really need `middleware('auth:api');` on this route? as I guess, this route is for registration, when you send this request you are guest (if I understood correctly) but this middleware only accept authenticated user

Comment: In this case it should show some authentication error rather than methodexception error

Comment: it also depends on your `Exception/Handler.php` . try to `dd()` in `unauthenticated` or `render` method, check if you are accessing it

Comment: remove  `->middleware('auth:api')` from your route and try

Comment: what do you mean "work with that"? you are trying to add authorized middleware to route, which shouldn't has it

Comment: I need to work with middleware. In other words I need to authenticate users before accessing my API.

Comment: in this case, user which trying to register, must be a registered user(if it makes sense)

Comment: This feature is available for those who are already registered. Think about the concept of Super admin and admin.

Comment: ok, so whats the problem then? do you provide user's token when you try to access this route? do you use passport `package`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the post url in the postman while making a request
the url you are using seems to be get url i.e  127.0.0.1:8000/user/register

if your route is

```
Route::post('/user','UserController@Register')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Use the below url in postman with method as post

127.0.0.1:8000/user